# Reproducing output from one statistical program to R

Tags: r, statistica

A previous employee from my organization performed all of their analyses on a different statistical program than R (with no documentation), and no one currently employed knows which program was used. Looking at the model output table and comparing it to Google search results, I think they used Statistica. In an effort to be transparent with other organizations who work with us, I'm trying to replicate their work and potentially reevaluate it.

**Model**: They modeled the relationship between three variables which I will call *A, B, C*. Variables were chosen based on exploratory analyses (i.e., correlation matrices and GLM modeling). Parameter estimates are used for prediction purposes. From what I can tell, they used a GLM with a log-link function to model *C* as a function of *A* and *B*.

**Data**:

```
A <- c(0.937918714, 1.277501774, 34.46428571, 3.843879361, 5.135520685, 0.324675325, 1.038421599, 0.333333333, 0.058139535, 0.09009009, 0.080515298, 5.174234424, 10.625, 21.9047619, 0.162074554, 2.372881356, 1.084430674, 18.53658537, 6.438631791, 0.172413793, 0.291120815, 9.090909091, 5.882352941)

B <- c(0.416666667, 0.555555556, 0.833333333, 0.4, 0.833333333, 0.4, 0.625, 0.625, 0.294117647, 0.37037037, 0.285714286, 1.111111111, 0.588235294, 0.476190476, 0.555555556, 0.833333333, 0.666666667, 0.476190476, 0.208333333, 0.163934426, 0.163934426, 0.3125, 0.454545455)

C <- c(0.009533367, 0.020812183, 0.056208054, 0.015002587, 0.042735043, 0.013661202, 0.004377736, 0.00635324, 0.001345895, 0.001940492, 0.00446144, 0.043768997, 0.021134594, 0.004471772, 0.023488256, 0.029441118, 0.052287582, 0.003526093, 0.030984508, 0.010891089, 0.020812686, 0.016032064, 0.018145161)
```

**My Approach**:

I combined each vector into a data frame (dat) and modeled using the following:

```
glm(formula = C ~ A + B, family = binomial(link = logit), data = dat)
```

**The Question**:

I notice we have different parameter estimates; in fact, their analysis includes 'Scale' as a factor, and an associated parameter estimate and standard error (see below). I haven't figured out how to include separate 'Scale' factor. My parameter estimates are close to these, but are obviously different with the inclusion of a new variable.

**Anyone familiar with this [Statistica] output and how I could replicate it in R? Primarily, how would I incorporate the Scale factor into my analyses?**

**Side-note**
I've also posted this to Reddit (r/rstats - Replicating an analysis performed in different software).

Much appreciated!

[image: OutputTableFromUnknownStatisticalProgram]

Comment: Maybe beta regression.  betareg in package betareg outputs a phi value which may be the reciprocal of the scale in your output.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for the wonderful suggestion! I ran a beta regression on this data and my parameter estimates are much closer. [Intercept: -5.0604] [A: 0.008626] [B: 1.935991]. Taking the reciprocal of phi: [phi: 0.009462]. 

I have two follow-up questions: 1) Would rounding differences between R and Statistica cause the parameter estimate disparities? 2) The resulting p-values are still quite different; the Intercept and B are still significant, but A is 0.52 using a beta regression. Any idea why that would be?

Really appreciate your comment!

Comment: Different algorithms could have different numerical properties.  There may be a difference even if the models are the same.

Comment: I can say that definitely looks like a Statistica results spreadsheet.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Perfect. Thanks for the confirmation!